# Retrieving number of iterations that ran for sparse linear solver in SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra

How to retrieve how many iterations ran to achieve specified tolerance level in [SciPy sparse linear system solvers](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solvers support a `callback` keyword argument that gets called after every iteration. So you could do something like this:

```
def solve_sparse(A, b):
  num_iters = 0

  def callback(xk):
    num_iters += 1

  # call the solver on your data
  return scipy.sparse.linalg.cg(A, b, callback=callback)[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python 3, the following works:

```
    def solve_sparse(A, b):
      num_iters = 0

      def callback(xk):
         nonlocal num_iters
         num_iters+=1

      x,status=scipy.sparse.linalg.cg(A, b,tol=1e-15, callback=callback)
      return x,status,num_iters
```

Answer (score 0):

A tiny change perimosocordiae's answer addressing the "UnboundLocalError":

```
def solve_sparse(A, b):
    solve_sparse.num_iters = 0

    def callback(xk):
        solve_sparse.num_iters += 1

    # call the solver on your data
    return scipy.sparse.linalg.cg(A, b, callback=callback)[0]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31210528)